# Confusion with how setState works

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am confused with how setState works.

Here is a portion of my code:

```js
handleBarsChange(value) {
  this.setState({numberOfbars: value});
  this.resetArray();
}
```

apparently, when the `resetArray()` function executes and tries to access the `this.state.numberOfbars` state variable, `setState` hasn't updated the value yet.

I want some explanation on how and where should the setState be executed and when can i expect to see the change.

Thank you!

Comment: *when can i expect to see the change* - the next render usually. However in the class `setState`, you may pass a callback that will be executed *after* the state has been updated. So you could do `this.setState({...}, this.resetArray())`

Comment: Have you tried searching this site for "setState asynchronous"? There have been a **lot** of question on this topic.

Comment: *And please don't give me react documentation links* - this isn't really a helpful attitude... If the docs are the place you need to be pointed to, you should be open to them - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous. It has a second callback argument that can be used to run code after a state transition. This isn't always the best approach, but with the very narrow example provided, it's hard to say.

```
this.setState({numberOfBars: value}, () => { this.resetArray() })
```

From the react docs:

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: But wont this lead to callback hell ? like in this example , everything is relatively simple; but suppose I need to do something more complex after a setState. how can I do that without just nesting callbacks ?

Comment: I suppose that's probably one of the reasons that last line is in the snippet I copied, "Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate for such logic. . .".

Comment: Thank you for the help man ! My bad I didn't see it. I should probably focus on reading documentation properly.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that `setState()` function is async so even if you run code after you call it, some state may not be updated yet.

The solution is implement a callback when the state was updated succesfully (`setState(<state>, <callback>)`), for example:

```
handleBarsChange(value){
    this.setState({numberOfbars: value}, () => {
        this.resetArray();
    });
}
```